# SharePoint 2013 Manage Reporting Services Application crashing

Tags: reporting-services, powerpivot, powerview

I had integrated reporting services working nicely, then I changed something and when I go into Manage Reporting Services Application -> System Settings this happens:

Sorry, something went wrong 
The server was unable to process the request due to an internal error.  For more information about the error, either turn on IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults (either from ServiceBehaviorAttribute or from the  configuration behavior) on the server in order to send the exception information back to the client, or turn on tracing as per the Microsoft .NET Framework SDK documentation and inspect the server trace logs. 
Technical Details

Troubleshoot issues with Microsoft SharePoint Foundation.

Correlation ID: 8f2c379c-c6fa-00dc-8176-66c8954ec13c

Date and Time: 8/9/2013 11:06:21 AM

---

I had all of this working, with power view running. Then I tried to create a BISM connection, and I must have changed something ,cause the wheels fell off!

I've check the log and it's not giving me a clear error, needless to say no reports or power views are working now. Any advice gratefully accepted.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the problem by deleting the application and proxy in Manage Service Applications and recreating a new service (with a different name just in case).